# CLI not working with save(); due to other observer checking for Role

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is my code. I have a simple batch script I'm testing. I can't get save() to work at all. I can get saveAttribute... to work.

All this simple test would be update status. We will use it for many other things, but I'm just getting the construct to work. It works off IDs --from 1 --to 500 for example. I've tried other scripts and same issue. Can't seem to isolate the issue.

```
<?php

$options = getopt('',array("from:","to:"));
if( !empty($options) &&
    isset($options['from']) &&
    isset($options['to']) )
{
    if(is_numeric($options['from']) && is_numeric($options['to'])){
        echo runScript($options['from'],$options['to']);
    }else {
        echo "Make sure parameters are numeric";
    }

}else{
    echo "Missing Arguments";
}

function runScript($from,$to){
    $_mage_file = 'app/Mage.php';
    if(file_exists($_mage_file)){
        require_once($_mage_file);
        umask(0);
        Mage::app();
        echo "Processing...";

        $_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                            'from' => $from,
                            'to' => $to
                        ))
                        ->load();


        foreach($_collection as $_product){


                try{

                    // BOF AC Script




//                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

            $_product->setData('status','2');
//                    $_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($_product, 'status'); //Works

                    // Save the values 
                  $_product->save();  //Doesn't work

                    // EOF AC Script


                }catch (Exception $e){
                    echo "Exception :". $e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                }


        }



    }   else{
        return "Please make sure script is at Magento root. app/Mage.php file not found";
    }


}
```

This script work just fine, but we have other observer that fire when a product is saved on the admin that only fire for certain roles.

Here is that script.
What I need is a way to work with both.

```
$admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();

$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();

$role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
```

Comment: try to init Magento app : `Mage::app('admin');` (after `require_once`)

Comment: I've already tried that...

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are log files enabled in the Magento backend?

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated the answer to what was the underlying cause, however the issue is still there.

Comment: I just have to unregister session. And it will ignore any observer that is getting fired for that session before save();!!!

Answer (score 0):

plaease change following in your foreach loop and in collection

```
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                        'from' => $from,
                        'to' => $to
                    ));

 foreach($_collection as $_product){


            try{

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

                $product->setData('status','2');
                $product->save();  
            }catch (Exception $e){
                echo "Exception :". $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
}
```

you are loading diff object and you are saving differnt object that is the issue I have updated foreach loop please check and let me know

Comment: Just fails, doesn't loop. get to the save();. I had to change $product_id to $_product->getId as it's in a colleciton.

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: I appreciate all the help, but it wasn't firing due to an observer checking for $admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

$adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();

$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();

$role_name = $role_data['role_name']; So of course one the save() fires it can't check for roles as it's an CLI

Comment: can you update your question so that I can understand now where is the mistake

Comment: Updated the question to what I found was the cause, but still have the issue.